# forEach overlay showing the same content

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

I have a forEach showing a row of different images (fitness exercises) when you click on the image I want to show a clip of that exercise (gif).

But it doesn't show the same gif from the document of the image clicked on, it only shows the gif from the first document.

How do I make it so when you click on the image it shows the right gif from the same document.

I am collecting the image and gif from firestore.

Javascript Code

```
   const exgif = document.getElementById("exercise-gif");

                const e = query(collection(db, "user", uid, "yourWorkouts", id, "exercises"));
                const un = onSnapshot(e, (querySnapshot) => {

                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                        console.log("exercises", doc.data());


                        const img = doc.data().image;
                        const exGif = doc.data().exGif;

                        exgif.innerHTML += `

                            <input type="image" id="toggle" src="${img}" class="ovr-ex-img" onclick="on()" />

                            <div id="over-exercise" onclick="off()">
                                <img class="ex-img" src="${exGif}">
                            </div>

                        `
                    });
                });  

function on() {
  document.getElementById("over-exercise").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("over-exercise").style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="" id="exercise-gif"></div>
```

Comment: Firstly, you have multiple elements with the same id, and your `on` and `off` event listeners are not tied to individual images.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by I have multiple elements with the same id, I only have 1 for each element I have an id for. The on and off function are tied to the div id over-exercise which shows that gif in it as it only covers part of the screen.

Comment: Id's are global, you can't have multiple elements with the same id even if they don't have the same parent

Comment: I don't have multiple elements with the same id.. Im not sure where you're seeing this?

Comment: Your loop `querySnapshot.forEach` is creating multiple elements (using `innerHTML`) and they all have id of `over-exercise`. You're making it difficult to get your problem solved.

Comment: yes, I get you now every foreach element would have the same id, and this is why it only shows the first one. I did think it was resetting when clicking but I didn't know how to word it. My only problem is on this page I show different work outs based on the id in the url (from firebase doc) all workouts have different number of workouts, so I though a forEach would be the best way.